# NavigationContainer show 'Can't find variable: React'

Tags: react-native, navigation

I already add:

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; 
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

it still show below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLyNh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of this file add,

```
import React from "react";
```